# Parsing JSON in Scala using ScalaObjectMapper

Tags: scala, jackson, objectmapper

I am trying to parse json using case class but running into an issue.

I have the following json

```
{
 "general": {
    "table": "123",
 },

 "employee" : {
    "table": "employee_data"
 },

 "fulltime" : {
    "table": "fulltime_employee_data"
 },

 "consultant" : {
    "table": "consultant_employee_data"
 } 
}
```

Here's my case class:

```
case class EmployeeInfo(employees: List[Map[String, String]])
```

I'm trying to parse the above json using the case class using the following code. It returns the object as null.

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
val str = Source.fromFile("employeeInfo.json").mkString
val temp = mapper.readValue[EmployeeInfo](str)
```

temp here is being returned as null. My json seems to be list of maps which is what I provided in my case class. Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. My case class needed the variable name as defined in the json.

```
case class EmployeeInfo(general: TableDetails, employee: TableDetails, fulltime: TableDetails, consultant: TableDetails)

class TableDetails {

val table: String = "" 

//getter and setter for table field

}
```